# How to do a program execution check

Tags: c++, qt

I have to execute following codes upon pressing a push button:

```
void stageProgram::on_pushButton_programKeyGrip_clicked()
{
   ManageConfigFile configFile; //---> line 1
   configFile.keyGripTest(pLabel); //---> line 2 
   tetra_grip_api::set_sensor_data_rate(SENSOR_ADDRESS_BROADCAST, 0); //--->line 3

   disconnect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &stageProgram::stimStatusEventHandler); //---> line 4
   disconnect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripSensorEvent,this, &stageProgram::sensorEventHandler); //--->line 5

   this->close(); //---> line 6
   keygripv2 = new ProgramKeyGripV2(pLabel);//---> line 7
   keygripv2 -> show();//---> line 8
}
```

I have a basic doubt: How do I make sure that the **first five** lines are executed successfully before executing lines 6,7 8 etc?

What's best programming practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is kind of hard to defined when a line is "executed successfully", because for that you need unit tests or at elast some bool checks...
you can for example make the app stop if some criteria is not fulfilled by just using Assertions...
like:

```
int divide(int a, int b)
{
    Q_ASSERT_X(b != 0, "divide", "division by zero");
    return a / b;
}
```

this assertion will stop the app if the variable b is zero...

now, a more easy approach is to check when the runtime executed an instruction of code(no matter if the result is ok or not..) for this
you can attach a **debug** output...  in qt there is QDebug

```
disconnect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &stageProgram::stimStatusEventHandler); //---> line 4

qDebug() << "tetraGripEvent disconnected";  //<----- like this

disconnect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripSensorEvent,this, &stageProgram::sensorEventHandler); //--->line 5

qDebug() << "tetraGripSensorEvent disconnected";  //<----- like this

this->close(); //---> line 6
```

now in your case is simple because, disconnect is actually a function that returns a boolean value...

see the [official doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect-3): where it states

> Disconnects signal in object sender from method in object receiver.
>   Returns ***true*** if the connection is successfully broken; otherwise
>   returns ***false***.

so you could do

```
auto flag{false};
flag = disconnect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this,    &stageProgram::stimStatusEventHandler); //---> line 4

qDebug() << "tetraGripEvent disconnected? " << flag;  //<----- like this
```